# Treat as empty submitted form if only date field is filled in

Tags: django, django-forms, inline-formset, form-fields

I have an inlineformset_factory with a couple of fields where `date = forms.DateField()` is one of them. If i submit an empty form there is no error. But if i submit it with only date filled in I get an error that the other fields are needed (what is the normal behaviour and it should work like this as those other fields are necessary in case of a valid form).

What I want is that if only the date field is filled in the form should be regarded as an empty form and an error is not raised. How can I do this?

The reason I want this is that I want to fill in the date field with the current date (via js) so the user doesn't need to fill that in as it the current date 9 out of 10 times.

Here is some reference code:

forms.py:

```
class FactuurItemsForm(forms.ModelForm):
class Meta:
    model = FactuurItems
    fields = [
            'datum', 'omschrijving', 'aantal', 'btw', 'prijs'
            ]
```

models.py:

```
class FactuurItems(models.Model):
    item_factuur = models.ForeignKey(Facturen, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    omschrijving = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    aantal = models.IntegerField(default=0)
    btw = models.IntegerField(choices=btws, default='21')
    prijs = models.DecimalField(max_digits=10, decimal_places=2, default=0)
    datum = models.DateField(null=True, blank=True)
    totaalprijs = models.DecimalField(max_digits=10, decimal_places=2, default=0, null=True, blank=True)
```

views.py:

```
FacturenFormSet = inlineformset_factory(Facturen, FactuurItems, form=FactuurItemsForm, 
                    extra=1,
                    fields=('omschrijving', 'aantal', 'btw', 'prijs', 'datum'),
```

Comment: con you post some reference code of how you implemented to that we can understand where the code is failing.

Comment: @PavanKumarTS added reference code. Actually just using vanilla inlineformset_factory with a model and form.